# how do i plug velocity data in a formula

Tags: r, frequency, velocity

(Rstudio) suppose I have a data set of:

```
Circle  X    Y
 A      21   8
 A      32   17
 A      23   32
 B      22   4
 B      43   12
 C      12   4
```

How do I plug this data and create a new data frame into this equation:
Vxn = ((X(max value))-(X(min value)))/(Frequency of each unique circle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by 'Circle', loop `across` the 'X', 'Y', columns get the difference of `max`, `min` value of that column divided by the number of elements, create new columns with suffix '_scale' by specifying the `.names`

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
    group_by(Circle) %>%
    mutate(across(c(X, Y), ~  (max(.) - min(.))/n(), .names = '{.col}_scale')) %>%
      ungroup
```

-output

```
df2
# A tibble: 6 x 5
#  Circle     X     Y X_scale Y_scale
#  <chr>  <int> <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 A         21     8    3.67       8
#2 A         32    17    3.67       8
#3 A         23    32    3.67       8
#4 B         22     4   10.5        4
#5 B         43    12   10.5        4
#6 C         12     4    0          0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Circle = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"), X = c(21L, 
32L, 23L, 22L, 43L, 12L), Y = c(8L, 17L, 32L, 4L, 12L, 4L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```